# Remove or disable red dot hover breakpoint in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to remove **red dot breakpoint**. I don't need that feature and It is showing if I accidentally hover on line number. So, can I completely remove that red dot on hover on line number?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the command palette using ctrl+shift+p. Select either workplace settings or user settings (depending on whether you want it to be across all your projects or just the current project). Add this line to your settings.json file and save:

```
"editor.glyphMargin": false
```